# Upload artifacts to Nexus through UI

Tags: maven-2, nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to create a pom bundle in Nexus3, but I get an error that the assets duplicate each other:

> WARNING
>
> The assets 1 and 2 have identical coordinates, The assets 2 and 3 have
>   identical coordinates, The assets 3 and 4 have identical coordinates,
>   The assets 4 and 5 have identical coordinates

Here is a screenshot of the upload page:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this case, you are generating a pom for 5 different jar files. Internally nxrm 3 will rewrite the name of these jar files to match what maven expects given the pom settings you have provided. In this case, all of these jar files will be named `libreoffice-uno-4.0.3.3.jar`. You have two options. You can upload each of these jar files with a separate pom file where the artifact name matches the name of the jar file. Alternatively you can give each jar file a classifier. That would cause the files to be named `libreoffice-uno-4.0.3.3-<classifier>.jar`.

Comment: The goal is to make each artifact available as a dependency.  By specifying the classifier upon upload, don't I have to also specify the classifier in the pom?  My goal is to create a bundle, which was an option in Artifactory (I think it was a virtual bundle).  Is there any way to do that in Nexus?

Comment: I’m not sure what a virtual bundle is but since it doesn’t directly map to anything in maven I’m aware of I can only guess artifactory is generating multiple Pom files for you. You can use classifiers just fine here. You just have to include them when requesting each dependency.

Comment: Or maybe you're expecting an aggregator pom and a child pom for each artifact? NXRM 3 doesn't have any way to do that. Each artifact uploaded needs to have their own coordinates for maven to work (classifiers being one way to accomplish that, separate coordinates being the other).

Comment: I forgot to follow up, but option 1 (pom for each artifact) is the route I took. Thanks.